# Submit MySQL Query Works From PHPMyAdmin But Not From TextArea

Tags: php, mysql

I want to submit javascript code formatted as plaintext to display a JS example on an HTML page.

When I submit the following snippet via SQL, the query runs successfully. However, when I submit the exact same text via a textarea which is properly connected to the DB, the query does not complete but does not display an error.

```
<text>
var input = document.getElementById(/'numberInput/');
if (input &lt; 0) {
alert(/'Number was negative./');
}else if(input &lt;= 10){
alert(/'Number was between 0 - 10/');
}else{
alert(/'Number was greater than 10./'); 
}
</text>
```

When I run the following query, the row is added succesfully...

```
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, 'data') 
VALUES (NULL, '<text>\r\nvar input = 
  document.getElementById(/\'numberInput/\');\r\n
    if (input &lt; 0) 
      {\r\n
      alert(/\'Number was negative./\');
      \r\n}
    else if(input &lt;= 10)
      {\r\n
      alert(/\'Number was between 0 - 10/\');
      \r\n}
    else{\r\n
      alert(/\'Number was greater than 10./\');\r\n}\r\n</text>'
      );
```

Below is the php code which accepts the string from the textarea and saves it in the var $data

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', '');

    if(!$con)
    {
        echo 'Error Connecting to DB Server';
    }

    if(!mysqli_select_db($con, 'a3'))
    {
        echo 'Error Selecting DB';
    }
    $data = $_POST['data'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO test (data) VALUES ('$data')";

    if(!mysqli_query($con,$query))
    {
        echo 'Error Inserting Page to DB';
    }else
    {
        echo 'Inserted Page to DB';
    }

    header("refresh:0; url=index.php");

?>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that's executing the query? My guess is you are not using a prepared statement and you are also not checking if the query worked. But that's just a hunch right now.

Comment: You're missing an `}` in the last else-clause. And as @rickdenhaan, - then please post the PHP-code you're exeuting, since that's where the hachet must be burried.

Comment: @zeth Added php code thanks

Comment: You don't get `Error Inserting Page to DB` when you execute this code? Instead of `mysqli_select_db` you can just put the DB name as the 4th parameter of the connection. The part that opens you to SQL injections here is also why this query fails to execute. Parameterize and I think this would work. Also use error reporting and the driver will tell you why it fails.